# MYSQL Data Source could not be found in my Add Connection from Server Explorer and Entity Data Model Wizard, asp.net

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql-server, entity-framework

I already downloaded  MySQL Connector/Net and reference the assembly MySql.Data.dll. But I still couldn't find the MYSQL Data Source in my Add connection from Server Explorer and Entity Data Model. Is there something that I'm missing thats why I'm not seeing it? I'm using ASP.NET. I already have a MYSQL database and I want to Generate it in my Entity Data Model as well as Add connection in my Server Explorer because as of now I'm using SQL Server .mdf.

[image]

Thanks for those who could help me.